# How to take a picture from camera without using intent in android studio

Tags: java, android, image, camera, snapshot

i am working on an android app. In which i am trying to implement the camera functionality and take a picture and save it in storage, without using the intent to avoid getting android built-in camera.

Comment: You might then consider building your camera using Camera2 API.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera

Answer (score 1):

CommonsWare's link is a good start. If you're strapped on time or lazy and need an in-app camera up and running I'd recommend using a library like https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2, which, coincidentally was developed by the guy(s) over CommonsWare.